# When is /tmp folder cleared in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I have a simple question. When is the /tmp folder cleared in Cygwin?

I have restarted my computer and none of the files in /tmp were cleared.

Can anyone answer this?

Comment: No process is clearing /tmp in Cygwin at restart, contrary to Linux/MacOS.

Comment: @somega : You can set up a cron job, which removes files of certain age from your temp folders.